# Combine 2 Observables rxjs

Tags: rxjs, observable

How can i use the return values of 2 combined Observables in the next?

I need to fetch the settings and the current Position first before creating the map.

```
let trackerObservable = this.tracker.getCurrentPosition();
let settingsObservable = this.user.loadSettings();

Observable.merge(trackerObservable, settingsObservable)
        .switchMap((coords: Coordinates, settings: Settings) => {
            this.currentCoords = coords;
            return this.navigatorMap.createMap(map_id, {
                lat: coords.latitude,
                lng: coords.longitude
            }, settings);
        }).subscribe(() => { [...] })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `forkJoin` to get both the observable data.

```
Observable
    .forkJoin(trackerObservable, settingsObservable)
    .map((data: Array<any>) => {
        let coords: data[0];
        let settings: data[1];
        this.currentCoords = coords;
        return this.navigatorMap.createMap(map_id, {
            lat: coords.latitude,
            lng: coords.longitude
        }, settings);
    });
```